# Java: Compare two strings when reading line by line in parallel

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to find a nice way to compare two strings when reading line by line in parallel.
The reason i want to do that without using equals method or such is because the strings are not exactly the same, to be more accurate i'll give an example.

```
String s1 = "aaa\nbbb\nccc\ddd"
String s2 = "aaa\n\rbbb\n\rccc\n\rddd"
```

As u can see both strings has same values when we are looking line by line (though are not completly equal since s2 has also \r in it).
Now, i know i can use some remove method to clean that "\r" but since the string can be very large, i prefer looping row by row and once the strings are not equal to break my logic.
In other words i prefer iterating only the needed rows instead of cleanning the entrie string from \r.

edited: i am not reading from a file. these are plain strings.

Any ideas :) ?

Comment: You can do `replaceAll("\r\n", "\n")` on both strings before comparing them.

Comment: I explained i dont want to do that..

Comment: I can't imagine why given you have to write much more code and the performance difference if they are equal is likely to be worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you said the string can be very large, I guess you are reading from a file. When you use  a BufferedReader and use the `readLine();` method, you will get line by line, without line separators. Now, you can use `equals()`.

```
BufferedReader reader1 = ...; // depends on your source
BufferedReader reader2 = ...; // depends on your source

String line1 = null;
String line2 = null;

while ((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null && (line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)
{
     if (line1.equals(line2))
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but I am not reading from a file, Also, can u expand how can it be done by parallel?

Comment: So, from where does the String come?

Comment: It's being generated with PrintStream object. Btw, if i use BufferedReader like u suggested, would it be a "big waste" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create two BufferedReader objects, one for each string and read line by line and compare the strings representing a line. The BufferedReader.readLine() method automatically strips the end of line chars (they are not added to the returned string).

BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(s1)); is how you get the buffered reader created.