# Regex matching loop never terminates

Tags: java, regex

I have an ASCII text file I am trying to use regex to parse in Java.  File example:

```
09-JUN-15 22:33     Eq:1    P1010030    1   HPCT: 0.0   RlTqCur:532 RlTqMin:-266    RlTqMax:270 ESMIN:2 ESMAX:2
```

I built my expressions, but I think I might be running into a possible runaway regex case.  My `while (m.find())` loop never terminates.

My regex pattern is very long.  Here is the problem area: `"(esmin:)(?<esmin>\\d+)"`

When I remove `(esmin:)` from the expression the while loop terminates as expected.  Am I breaking a regex rule?  I'm not sure why I'm having difficulties.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Fixed the missing ")" sorry, that isn't the problem.  And yes I am using a case insensitive flag in the pattern.  Here is some more code:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexData.getJobDataType1(),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(fileData);


    while (m.find()) {


    }
```

**EDIT2:** The issue as pointed out below by stribizhev is that the string I'm reading in `fileData` is actually the whole entire ASCII file.

Comment: Do you mean `(esmin:)(?<esmin>\\d+)`? You need to use a case-insensitive modifier: `(?i)(esmin:)(?<esmin>\\d+)`. Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/fLef8n).

Comment: This cannot be reproduced with the code (not) given, and the data - is is a *file* or a *string*?

Comment: @stribizhev Case-insensitiv could be set by a flag in the compile call. And, by itself, it would not  cause a non-terminating loop.

Comment: But the regex is not valid, there is no closing `)` for the `esmin` group.

Comment: Which would throw an exception - again, not a non-terminating loop. - The question is broken.

Comment: Chances are that the "very long" regex pattern runs into excessive backup operations, something that is frequently assumed to be a non-terminating loop.

Comment: @stribizhev - Edited post.  Still same issue.

Comment: Ok, it seems you are using this regex on the whole log file contents. Read line by line and apply the regex to each line separately.

Comment: @stribizhev - that is correct.  Oops, I did not know I had to do this.  I will see how I go about correcting that.

Comment: @stribizhev Even when fileData contains many lines from a text file there's no reason for a non-terminating loop. But very long running backup becomes much more likely.

Comment: Just a note: `Pattern.DOTALL` is redundant as you do not have `.` in your pattern. Use [`BufferedReader`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120461/java-compare-two-strings-when-reading-line-by-line-in-parallel) to read line by line from the file, and see if it helps.

Comment: @laune - perhaps I never waited long enough for it to actually be non-terminating.  However, the text file is only maybe 60 lines.

Comment: @stribizhev - The `BufferedReader` seems to have corrected the issue.  The loop now terminates in less than a second.  You can add an answer I will accept if you like.  Thank you!

Comment: @user432209 60 lines is *a lot* for the order of magnitude backups can reach. A pity you haven't shown the regex in full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your expected value resides on a single line, you are much safer reading the whole input line by line.

Use `BufferedReader` for that.

As an example:

```
BufferedReader reader = ...; // initialize the reader
String line = null;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexData.getJobDataType1(),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);    
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{
     Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
     while (m.find()) {
            // Process the match
     }
}
```

Note that `Pattern.DOTALL` modifier only change the behavior of a dot inside the pattern, not matching the dots inside an input string. Since your pattern is `(esmin:)(?<esmin>\\d+)`, i.e. it does not have a period inside it, the modifier is redundant. If you need to match float values (not just integer ones), use `[+-]?\\d*\\.?\\d+` instead of `\\d+`.

Comment: You pointed out that `Pattern.DOTALL` is redundant if no `.` in pattern.  Does this include floating numbers, aka `0.0` or `13.56`?  Thanks,

Comment: I added some explanation. The dots inside regex patterns are affected by that modifier, not the actual literal dots inside input strings.

Comment: In which case, yes I do have a `.` elsewhere in my pattern.  Strangely enough, both ways work with/without `Pattern.DOTALL`.

Comment: Because now, you are reading the text *line by line*, you just no longer need that modifier. :)